# What are the flow properties for the engines of a Fokker 70 with reversers deployed?

Tags: landing, thrust-reverser, fokker-70

I want to know what the approximate flow properties would be at the exit of the nozzle for a Fokker 70 with reversers deployed. What is the exit velocity of gas at the nozzle?

How do they calculate values of reverse thrust? Can anyone explain what the range of thrust settings is when using bucket reversers?

Comment: It would be noteworthy to name the engine type. The Fokker 70 uses Rolls-Royce RB.183 Tay 620-15 engines.